# plot errorbars in background

Tags: matplotlib

I'm using matplotlib to plot point with relative error bars. I plotted empty points in this way:

```
plt.errorbar(x,y, yerr=[y1,y2], marker='o', markeredgecolor='red', markerfacecolor='none')
```

How is possible to let error bars to go in the background?

Comment: You have to be more specific. In the background of what? Behind a plotted line, behind the grid? In any case, you can try the `zorder` argument in the function call.

Comment: I mean behind the point. Being the point empty what I get is and error bar that crosses it..
I tried with zorder but it does not work.

Comment: Use `markerfacecolor='white'` in function call. You cannot "hide" an errorbar behind something transparent, as the markerface is with `markerfacecolor='none'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `markerfacecolor='white'` option in the function call, as this will hide the errorbar behind the markerpoint.